# Integral version of the lebesgue differentation theorem

Tags: integration, harmonic-analysis, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Given $f\in L^p(B_1)$, where $B_1$ is the unit ball centered at $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, we know that the point $a\in B$ such that
$$
\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{|B(a,r)|} \int_{B(a,r)} |f-(f)_{B(a,r)}|^p =0
$$
have full measure in $B$, where $(f)_{B(a,r)}$ is the average of $f$ on the ball $B(a,r)$ of center $a$ with radius $r$. 
I wounder if there is an integral version of the kind : for $\frac{1}{2}>r>0$ consider
$$\phi_r : a \in B(0,\frac{1}{2}) \mapsto \int_{B(a,r)} |f-(f)_{B(a,r)}|^p\ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \  \psi_r : a\in B(0,\frac{1}{2})\mapsto \int_{B(a,r)} |f|^p
$$
Is there a $q\geq 1$, such that
$$
\Vert \phi_r \|_{L^q(B(0,r))} \underset{r\to 0}{=} o \left( \Vert \psi_r\Vert_{L^q(B(0,r))} \right)
$$
Or is there a weaker space $X$, such as Lorentz space, for which we can exchange the $L^q$ norm with the norm on $X$ ?

Comment: In the case $q=1$, we can separate the integral $$ \int_{B(0,r)} \phi_r = \int_{B(0,r)\cap \{\phi_r\leq r^d\}} \phi_r + \int_{B(0,r)\cap \{ \phi_r>r^d\}} \phi_r$$. The first integral is bounded by $r^{2d}$ and the second by $$|\{x\in B(0,r) : \frac{1}{r^d}\int_{B(x,r)} |f-(f)_{B(x,r)}|^p>1\}| \int_{B(0,2r)} |f|^p $$

Comment: Using the same technics as for the proof of the boundedness of the maximal functions in harmonic analysis, we can obtain that for almost every $a\in B(0,1/2)$, $$ |\{ x \in B(a,r) : \frac{1}{r^d} \int_{B(x,r)} |f-(f)_{B(a,r)}|^p >1 \}|/r^d \to 0\ \ \ \text{as } r\to 0 $$ Hence, we get that for almost every $a\in B(0,1/2)$, $$\int_{B(a,r)} \phi_r = o\left( r^{3d/2} + r^d\psi_{2r}(a) \right) $$